# Spark : How to reuse the same array schema that has all fields defined across the data-frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have hundreds of columns a,b,c ... . I would like to modify dataframe schema, where each array will have the same shape `date`, `num` and `val` field.

There are thousands of `id` so I would like to modify ONLY schema not dataframe. Modified schema will be used in the next step to load data to dataframe efficiently . I would like to avoid using UDF to modify whole dataframe.

Input schema:

df.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- num: long (nullable = true) !!! NOTE : `num` !!!
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

Required Output schema:

```
root
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- num: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- num: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- num: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- num: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

To reproduce input Schema:

```
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([
  """{"id":1,"a":[{"date":2001,"num":1},{"date":2002,},{"date":2003,}],"b":[{"date":2001,"val":4},{"date":2002,"val":5},{"date":2003,"val":6}],"d":[{"date":2001,"val":21},{"date":2002,"val":22},{"date":2003,"val":23}],"c":[{"date":2000,"val":30},{"date":2001,"val":31},{"date":2002,"val":32},{"date":2003,"val":33}]}""",
  """{"id":2,"a":[{"date":2001,"num":2},{"date":2002},{"date":2003}],"b":[{"date":2001,"val":4},{"date":2002,"val":5},{"date":2003,"val":6}],"d":[{"date":2001,"val":21},{"date":2002,"val":22},{"date":2003,"val":23}],"c":[{"date":1990,"val":39},{"date":2000,"val":30},{"date":2001,"val":31},{"date":2002,"val":32},{"date":2003,"val":33},{"date":2004,"val":34}]}}"""
]))


 for field in df.schema:
    print(field)
```

Print output:

```
StructField(a,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(date,LongType,true),StructField(num,LongType,true),StructField(val,LongType,true))),true),true)
StructField(b,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(date,LongType,true),StructField(val,LongType,true))),true),true)
StructField(c,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(date,LongType,true),StructField(val,LongType,true))),true),true)
StructField(d,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(date,LongType,true),StructField(val,LongType,true))),true),true)
StructField(id,LongType,true)
```

Solution (see OneCricketeer answer below for details) :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, LongType, ArrayType

jsonstr=[
  """{"id":1,"a":[{"date":2001,"val":1,"num":1},{"date":2002,"val":2},{"date":2003,"val":3}],"b":[{"date":2001,"val":4},{"date":2002,"val":5},{"date":2003,"val":6}],"d":[{"date":2001,"val":21},{"date":2002,"val":22},{"date":2003,"val":23}],"c":[{"date":2000,"val":30},{"date":2001,"val":31},{"date":2002,"val":32},{"date":2003,"val":33}]}""",
  """{"id":2,"a":[{"date":2001,"val":1},{"date":2002,"val":2},{"date":2003,"val":3}],"b":[{"date":2001,"val":4},{"date":2002,"val":5},{"date":2003,"val":6}],"d":[{"date":2001,"val":21},{"date":2002,"val":22},{"date":2003,"val":23}],"c":[{"date":1990,"val":39},{"date":2000,"val":30},{"date":2001,"val":31},{"date":2002,"val":32},{"date":2003,"val":33},{"date":2004,"val":34}]}}"""
]

array_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    
    StructField('date' ,LongType(),True),
    StructField('num' ,LongType(),True),
    StructField('val' ,LongType(),True)]),
    True)


keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
fields = [StructField(k, array_schema, True) for k in keys] 
fields.append(StructField('id',LongType(),True))
df_schema = StructType(fields)

dff = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(jsonstr),df_schema)
```

Comment: Use a list of Map types instead of a Struct if you don't want to list each pairing of `date, num, val`

Comment: I will try this but if anybody knows how to apply MapType on my example, I wil accept it as working solution: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-maptype-dict-examples/

Comment: You'll still need to list out "hundreds of map types" (but how are you getting hundreds of letters?). But that would ultimately be the same thing as extracting out the ArrayType/StructType to a variable that you can reuse within each outer StructField. Plus, what does `NOTE : num` mean? Yes, you defined it for the first array, but none of the others, so it doesn't exist for anything but the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the true solution is to have consistent names, or at least something more descriptive if the fields are truly different. "num" and "val" are basically synonymous

If I understand the question, you want to reuse the same array schema that has all fields defined

```
array_schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField('date' ,LongType(),False),StructField('num' ,LongType(),True),StructField('val' ,LongType(),True))),True) 

df_schema = StructType([
StructField('a',array_schema,True)
StructField('b',array_schema,True)
...
StructField('id',LongType(),True)
])
```

Or you can do this in a loop, which is safe because it's applied in the Spark driver

```
keys = ['a', 'b'] 
fields = [StructField(k, array_schema, True) for k in keys] 
fields.append(StructField('id',LongType(),True))
df_schema = StructType(fields)
```

(change each boolean to a False if there will be no nulls)

Then you need to provide this schema to your read function

```
spark.read.schema(df_schema).json(...
```

If there will still be more fields that cannot be consistently applied to all "keys", then use `ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), LongType()), False)`

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what i'm looking for. i can not run `array_schema`  there are some  problems array_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField('date' ,LongType,True),
    StructField('num' ,LongType,True),
    StructField('val' ,LongType,True
    )]),
    True )   I get AssertionError: dataType <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'> should be an instance of <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'>

Comment: You're missing parentheses